# Using Phing programmatically

Tags: php, phing

Does anyone use/have examples of using Phing from PHP? I'd quite like a web interface for Phing and am wondering how easily this could be achieved.

[Edit] In this specific instance we're deploying from Subversion using Phing.

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you like to do with Phing?

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'web interface' for Phing as such as far as I know. However you may be interested in using Jenkins/Hudson for what you're doing. You'll find that those two work together very well and when properly set up Jenkins will basically become your web interface to Phing.
See http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2009/11/09/continuous-integration-for-php-using-hudson-and-phing/ and http://jenkins-ci.org/.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have come across Hudson (although not tried it - I will look again) and realise that there is no (that I've been able to find) web interface to Phing - I am interested in making one though, that's what I was asking about!